# Concatenating specific strings in 2 columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

What I have:

```
Month|Year
 Jan |2019
 Feb |2019
 Jan |2020
 Feb |2020
```

What I want is to add another column:

```
Month|Year|month_yr
 Jan |2019|Jan19
 Feb |2019|Feb19
 Jan |2020|Jan20
 Feb |2020|Feb20
```

What I tried:

```
df2['month_yr']=df2.month + df2.year
```

But this is giving me Jan2019,Jan2020 etc. I do not want the full year but the last 2 digits like Jan19,Jan20 etc

Thank You

Comment: `df2['month_yr']=df2.month + df2.year.str[-2:]`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
df2['month_yr']=df2.month + df2['Year'].str[-2:]
```

this should work